# How to select extracted time from timestamp?

Tags: postgresql

Select
extract (time from timestamp)
From tableA
where time = '12:00:00'

It shows an error that the column doesn't exist so how to select that??

Comment: Is there a column named "time" in the table? If not...error.

What is the column named from which you extract the time?
What are you trying to achieve if I may ask?

Comment: Also `extract` requires you specify a particular component of a `timestamp`, for instance:`select extract(HOUR from '2022-04-23 08:20'::timestamp);`.

Comment: Yes you are right but how to select that extracted column

Comment: Read the manual: [Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

Comment: You need to provide more information 1) Is `time`(not a good name by the way) of one of the datetime types; `timestamp, timestamptz, time, or date`? 2) What is the complete error message?